# How HTTP.sys will map the req to that particular website apllication pool?

Tags: iis

I am learning IIS. So when ever the application pool is created the id of that will be registered with HTTP.sys. So when the request come from client how it will found that request is belong to that particular id?

Then What is the use of Web Admin Services (WAS) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously from IIS configuration (metabase or applicationHost.config) you can see a mapping for request path (such as /vdir1/file1.aspx) to an application pool. Such mappings are also loaded into http.sys, so that it can map incoming requests to the expected application pool.

WAS is a service that create/dispose w3wp.exe instances. It also reads IIS configuration to know how many application pools are there, and how to create worker processes based on the setting. BTW, its official name is Windows Process Activation Service.

Comment: Then i am not able to post any questions.Because two of my questions where closed.So after read the reason i have changed those questions.But no one is responding.I dont know how to get access for posting questions.Can you tell me how to?

Comment: Such penalty should be time limited. Honestly speaking I have no idea how to recover the rights. Can you try to start from http://stackoverflow.com/faq?

Comment: Thanks..Actually now i got the access. Because someone undownvoted that post.